# Use Container Metrics from Prometheus

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, prometheus

I deployed Prometheus on my cluster as well as cAdvisor and Grafana. It works tremendously well. I get all the data I need on Grafana's UI.
I started using Prometheus Java API in order to use this data. For example get the CPU usage and if it has a certain value something will be done.

What I display on Grafana is the Container CPU usage for each container. Now I would like to get that information with the Java API if possible (or something if not). But of course the PromQL queries aren't usable from a Java program (from what I tried but I may be wrong).

I thought of several ways:

- Clone the cAdvisor project and directly implement what I want to do in Go
- Create a bash script with the docker stat command that would get me the container and CPU usage associated
- Or maybe there is actually a way to send PromQL queries.
  For instance we get the metric by its name via Java or the Prometheus interface:

ex: `node_cpu` would get me some data.
But if I want something more precise, I need to send a request, for example `irate(node_cpu{job="prometheus"}[5m])` which is not possible via Java.

*Is there a way for me to get more precise metrics ?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prometheus supports REST API requests, which are language-agnostic. You just need to send an HTTP request with *your query* and process the response.

see an example below, copied from their site.

the following HTTP GET request:

```
http://localhost:9090/api/v1/query?query=up&time=2015-07-01T20:10:51.781Z
```

returns something like this:

```
{
   "status" : "success",
   "data" : {
      "resultType" : "vector",
      "result" : [
         {
            "metric" : {
               "__name__" : "up",
               "job" : "prometheus",
               "instance" : "localhost:9090"
            },
            "value": [ 1435781451.781, "1" ]
         },
         {
            "metric" : {
               "__name__" : "up",
               "job" : "node",
               "instance" : "localhost:9100"
            },
            "value" : [ 1435781451.781, "0" ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

lots more details, [here](https://prometheus.io/docs/querying/api/)